# Configure PHP and PostgreSQL on Windows

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm installing PHP, Apache and PostgreSQL Manually

PHP and Apache now is connected, but PostgreSQL is not connected to PHP.

i test by using phpinfo();

i also configure in php.ini like this :

```
extension=php_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
```

But why it's not work.

Thanks

Comment: What does "not connected to PHP" mean?  That you don't see the Postgres module in the output of `phpinfo()` ?  Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Did you restart your web server?

Comment: i don't see PostgreSQL in phpinfo();

Comment: yes, i restated the web server

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This tutorial](http://blog.lysender.com/2010/08/php-and-postgresql-on-windows/) worked for me:

> The PHP extension will look for `libpq.dll` which is found of your
>   PostgreSQL installation. The simple fix is to add the path than
>   contains that file to your environment PATH.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with PHP7 and Apache 2.4 on Windows 10. For me the solution was to add the following line to `httpd.conf`;

```
LoadFile "C:/php7/libpq.dll"
```

This also means that it's not required to have PostgreSQL installed if you just want to connect a PostgreSQL database that's not running on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

1) Installing PostgreSQL for Windows

2) add to your enviroment variable "PATH" the bin folder of PostgreSQL installation:
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\bin; (for example)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have installed PostgreSQL and your WAMP installation is on c:\wamp, you will need to copy
c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\libpq.dll   to   c:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\bin

Make sure you also have the following files
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\ext\php_pdo_pgsql.dll   and
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\ext\php_pgsql.dll

Also, make sure you have enabled the above 2 files as extensions, either via the WAMP menu (click on WAMP icon on taskbar, PHP, PHPExtensions, find the above 2 and 'check' them)

Please note that php5.3.9 and Apache2.2.11 refer to my specific PHP and Apache versions.
Adjust those to suit your installation.

That's it!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on Windows:

- Found `php.ini` in php folder.
- Found this line and removed “;”.

  ```
  ;extension=php_pgsql.dll
  ```

Answer (score 0):

in my case there are 2 php.ini, I had to uncomment extension pdo_pgsql in both php.ini

1. in php folder
2. in apache folder

both inside in wamp folder

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP in IIS, using PHP Manager, enable this extension:

```
php_pgsql.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, first I checked the location of php.ini file using this command-

- `php -i | find /i "Configuration File"`

After that I followed that location and find the line

- `;extension=pdo_pgsql`

Finally I remove the comment operator and the line marked as like this

- `extension=pdo_pgsql`