# Integrating PostgreSQL and Apache 2.4

Tags: php, windows, apache, postgresql, integration

I have Apache installed and running PHP, and I also have PostgreSQL installed, however, I am entirely unsure as to how to integrate PostgreSQL and Apache. I am using a windows environment.

Comment: I was all ready to help until that last sentence. Good luck my friend.

Comment: Thank you! I honestly wish I wasn't but it is a project requirement.

Comment: Its doeable, I did in the past but you have to do research and tries , start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518694/configure-php-and-postgresql-on-windows. Google is your friend, even older tutorials are good. For info I use vagrant now with a minimal centos VM, never been more happy.

Comment: What do you mean by "integration"? PostgreSQL like any other DB is a separate thing, you only need to use pgsql or php_pgsql to connect to it, and that's it.