# Win10/Apache/PHP8: PHP cannot load pgql library

Tags: php, postgresql, apache

I want to get postgres working with Apache / PHP8 on Windows 10.
For this I have activated the corresponding DLLs in php.ini:

```
extension_dir = "./../../server/php8/ext/"

...

extension=pdo_sqlite
extension=pgsql
```

After that I **restarted** the Apache web server. However, I get the following error messages in the Apache error log.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_pgsql' (tried: ./../../server/php8/ext/pdo_pgsql (The specified module was not found), ./../../server/php8/ext/php_pdo_pgsql.dll (The specified module was not found)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pgsql' (tried: ./../../server/php8/ext/pgsql (The specified module was not found), ./../../server/php8/ext/php_pgsql.dll (The specified module was not found)) in Unknown on line 0
```

I took a look at the `php8/ext` folder to be sure that the `.dll` files are
I took a look at the `php8/ext` folder to make sure the `.dll` files were there. And yes, both **exist**:

```
php_pgsql.dll
php_pdo_pgsql.dll
```

Did I miss something to get postgres running? Before using postgres I used mysql and that worked fine without trouble.

- Win10
- PHP8
- Apache 2.4.52
- Postgres 14.1

**EDIT:** [Configure PHP and PostgreSQL on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518694/configure-php-and-postgresql-on-windows) **does not answer my question**. The link of posted in the accepted answer does not work anymore.